# How to set up HTTPS with flask and node.js?

Tags: node.js, ssl, flask, https

On a linux server, I have a node.js web server that hosts a UI, and a flask webserver that holds the API for a neo4j database that the UI hits to get database information. I am setting up HTTPS for the app, should the configuration for it go into the flask web server or the node.js server? I have seen it set up with the flask web server only and don't know why/how this works. Thanks!

Comment: Are your clients talking to both, or is node.js proxying for flask?

Comment: Clients hit the node.js UI, the node.js UI retrieves database info by requesting from flask neo4j API. The client shouldn't directly request anything from flask.

Comment: Sounds like your answer is to do it on the node.js side. whether to secure the backend API is a matter of deployment.

Comment: BTW it's common to do https on a load balancer like nginx instead of in node. Again a matter of deployment.